# date parsefailure to convert in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash-grok, grok

**Mon Nov 18 09:38:45 2019**

Is there any idea on how to convert this above date so that it can be digest in grok filter ?
Here is what i did but still date parsefailure is there in logstash

```
date { match => ["starttime","E MMM dd HH:mm:s yyyy"]
       target => starttime  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong the filter. You need to specify that you want a Grok match and give it a name. In addition, it seems that your date format does not follow any of the standards (that can be checked in [Github](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns)), so you'll need a custom one that adjusts to your format. Something like this should work:

```
grok {
    match => { "starttime" => "%{DAY} %{MONTH} %{MONTHDAY} %{TIME} %{YEAR}"}
}
```

This should go inside your filter and then you can use `starttime` as you wish.

Comment: Hi @Drubio , Thanks so much for this idea. i will try to apply asap but one more issue like will elasticsearch understand this and identify this as a date or timestamp ?

Comment: @zz10 I think that depends on how you use it and what you wanna use it for. But, in general you may need to declare it as a `date` data type. Take a look at these resources since I think they are what you are looking for: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-change-data-type-for-date-field/28843 and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html